# How to resolve the undefined symbol of magic_setparam in /lib64/libmagic.so.1 ？

Tags: rhel, shared-library

I have successfully installed the command `s3cmd` (1.6.1) that I downloaded from the s3tools official web site. So the `s3cmd` software should be all right, and also the system `libmagic.so.l` itself is no problem.

Can anyone tell me wherever might be something wrong or missing when executing the `s3cmd` program？

```
Error loading some components of s3cmd (Import Error)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Invoked as: /bin/s3cmd
Problem: AttributeError: /lib64/libmagic.so.1: undefined symbol: magic_setparam
S3cmd:   1.6.1
python:   2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
environment LANG=en_US

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3cmd-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/s3cmd", line 2900, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/S3/S3.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/magic.py", line 293, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /lib64/libmagic.so.1: undefined symbol: magic_setparam
```

#### Other details

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
Release:        7.4
Codename:       Maipo

$ rpm -qf /lib64/libmagic.so.1
file-libs-5.11-35.el7.x86_64

$ nm -D /lib64/libmagic.so.1|grep -Ei "setpar"
```

Comment: Have you tried running “yum update /lib64/libmagic.so.1” so you are using the up to date package?  Most likely the AWS tools were built against a recent version of the OS.

Comment: Thanks！  But the system libmagic.so.1 has already been the latest version for RHEL 7！